# How to modify SQL SELECT results

Tags: sql, function

I need to write a SQL function that will allow me to strip an email address to the bare domain name.  EX: I would make JoeSchmoe@mail.google.com read as JoeSchmoe@google.com.  This is most likely very simple but, I cannot seem to find any information on it.

Comment: What exact rules do you want for the replacement? only use the top level domain (com in your case) and the second level domain (google in your case)?

Comment: What RDBMS? IF SQL Server maybe there's something in the .NET libraries. A simple count of dots won't work because of TLDs like `co.uk`

Answer (score 0):

If  you are using Oracle:

```
select substr('test@test.com',instr('test@test.com','@')+1,length('test@test.com')) as domain from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try creating a CLR SQL function and use regex from your .net library to parse the string.  From the looks of it you may have to parse the ccTLD if it exists and then parse the generic TLD/domain name.